# I want to know Ejabberd is free or not

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I want to know about ejabberd is free or not, because I want to decide from openfire and ejabberd before started development of application

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read through the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask a question that is acceptable in the forum. Also try to use google search, go to the homepage of Ejabberd to find out if its free or not. You should be able to find it on their page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of ejabberd: eCS and eBE. The former is a "community server" and is licensed under GPL. The latter is a "business edition" and has a commercial license.

Comment: Hi thank you for response, I would like to know difference in both version.